# Why the conditional sum of square is growing to infinite in time series ARMA model?

Tags: time-series, arima

I am trying to using conditional sum of sqaure(CSS) as loss function to estimate the coefficients of AR&MA parts and intercept, setting first few residual to be 0. But I notice that sometimes residuals increase rapidly to a really great number. And then the CSS and gradients are so big that I can not conduct gradient descent like BFGS to solve the loss function. In this case, what should I do?